# How do I send a real signed email in python?

Tags: python, email, m2crypto, smime

I have followed [this example](http://proj.badc.rl.ac.uk/svn/ndg-security/branches/Dependencies/m2crypto/doc/howto.smime.html) to send a signed email in python.

The problem is that I need to be able to send an email that has plain text, HTML text and other attachments.  When I try this, all I get in the end email is the plain text.

Here is my code:

```
from M2Crypto import BIO, Rand, SMIME

signEmail(plainText + htmlConent)

def makebuf(text):
    return BIO.MemoryBuffer(text)

def signEmail(message):

   buf = makebuf(message)

   # Instantiate an SMIME object; set it up; sign the buffer.
   s = SMIME.SMIME()
   s.load_key('signer_key.pem', 'signer.pem')
   p7 = s.sign(buf)

   # Recreate buf.
   buf = makebuf(message)

   # Output p7 in mail-friendly format.
   out = BIO.MemoryBuffer()
   out.write('From: sender@example.dom\n')
   out.write('To: recipient@example.dom\n')
   out.write('Subject: M2Crypto S/MIME testing\n')
   s.write(out, p7, buf)

   return out.read()
```

Comment: It works without the signing, right? Just to rule out problems constructing the message.

Comment: If someone is trying to use this, be aware that the code is basically straight from here https://tools.ietf.org/doc/python-m2crypto/howto.smime.html and M2Crypto currently (2017) only works for Python 2